# Xamarin Forms - Copy Project Error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, error-handling, xamarin.forms, runtime-error

I have an application created in Xamarin.Forms (PCL). I always tend to make multiple backup copies every day, so i just copy the project and paste it to my hard-drive or somewhere else. The problem is that the (now) copied project does not work properly, it gives me this error, as soon as i click on any button in the first activity of my app:
[image]

The original copy works perfectly fine.

[I have followed this link for the fix to this issue](https://releases.xamarin.com/common-issues-in-the-xamarin-15-2-2-release-being-tracked-by-the-xamarin-team/)

It basically tells me to copy the 'Mono.Posix.dll' and paste into the “Xamarin.VisualStudio” extension directory.

Needless to say, it does not work.

It doesn't make sense, that the original version works, while the copied ones don't.

*I am using Visual Studio Community Version 2017

Comment: I would try cleaning the solution (and/or manually deleting all the bin and obj folders).  And learn how to use source control

Comment: I did try Cleaning/Deleting the bin and obj folders.

Comment: Perhaps you might try uninstalling the app from the device. If you do not see the app icon on the device home screen, make sure to open the Settings app -> Apps (or Application Manager) -> then look for the app's **Package name** and uninstall it.